# How to match junk characters in mysql database with arabic letters with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arabic

My question in brief here:

The site is developed with PHP as front end and mysql as backend.

I am registering in my site by entering the arabic letters. And the value also inserted in mysql database. But it is not in the format what i entered. It looks like junk words.

Now my problem is when i try to login i can't able to match the input what i entered. I am stuck with this place.

Any ideas or suggestion will be helpful and grateful.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

This problem should be solved in an earlier stage. Arabic character do not fit in a non-unicode databasetable. That's the real problem.

You should use Unicode tables as well as a Unicode connection to your MySQL database.

Set the default character set of your table to utf8 and make sure the connection to your database is also using this character set:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);
```

See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Check the character set of your current connection with:

```
echo mysql_client_encoding($conn);
```

See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-client-encoding.php

When creating your tables do something like this:

```
create table user (
    // Your table definition
) default charset = UTF8
```

If you have done these things and add a user which contains arabic character to your table, you will see it is displayed correct. Now the comparison will be easy.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I fixed it.

you can alternatively include a *php* code below:

`mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);` `$conn`, is our mysql connection.
you may also need to include the meta tag in your web page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

hope that helps

Sardar Jaf