# Selecting Arabic characters results in question marks in MYSQL. How to fix?

Tags: php, mysql, select, encoding, arabic

The `select` statement for Arabic characters returns `?????` .. why ?

php code :

```
<?php

    require_once("db.php");
    $code=$_GET["code"];
    $query = "SELECT id,name,price,code from metro_goods where code=$code";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $arr=array();
    $i=0;

    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $arr[$i]=array("id"=>$row['id'],"name"=>$row['name'],"price"=>$row["price"],"code"=>$row["code"]);
        $i++;
    }
        echo json_encode(array("data"=>$arr));
 ?>
```

the result :

```
{"data":[{"id":"55121","name":"???? ??? ????? - ???","price":"16","code":"42217572"}]}
```

edit:

when setting char-set

```
$rating_conn = mysql_connect($rating_dbhost, $rating_dbuser, $rating_dbpass) or die  ('Error connecting to mysql');
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$rating_conn);
```

the output becomes :

```
{"data":[{"id":"55121","name":"\u0645\u0632\u064a\u0644 \u0639\u0631\u0642 \u0646\u064a\u0641\u064a\u0627 - \u0633\u062a\u0643","price":"16","code":"42217572"}]}
```

Comment: Which is the encoding for the database? How did you insert/update that data?

Comment: Are you using MySQL client? If yes, I guess then MySQL command line client do not supports UTF8 chars

Comment: @orique it's Collation : utf8_general_ci  .. and I have inserted as I run insert query on the database like this insert into table(col1) values('مرحبا')

Comment: @Adham: What MySQL client are you using? or you have to use it on Web? If any other case please specify

Comment: before executing your query, execute "mysql_query("set names utf8")"

Comment: You're doing [zero SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) here so it's a miracle it runs at all. Do not use `mysql_query`, use PDO or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: Yes, you have to set the MySQL connection encoding in order for the databas to return proper UTF-8. The output of your JSON is then correct. See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to match junk characters in mysql database with arabic letters with PHP and MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997087/how-to-match-junk-characters-in-mysql-database-with-arabic-letters-with-php-and)

Comment: Run this query and make sure all results are set to UTF8: **SHOW VARIABLES WHERE variable_name LIKE '%char%' OR variable_name LIKE '%colla%'**

Answer (score 1):

Before you do any query you have to assign the charset encoding to UTF8 with the following query statement:

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");